# Can Konami accept a Yu-Gi-Oh card that I made?

Tags: yu-gi-oh, playing-cards

I made a Yu-Gi-Oh card but it is not broken like current broken Yu-Gi-Oh cards and here it is to see but please before you make your decision about it take another look on ''dragun of red eyes''.
[image]

Answer (score 9):

In general, creative industries have a hard policy not to even *look* at fan submissions. Why? Because if they do look at fan submissions and later come up with something similar to the fan submission, they put themselves at risk if the fan claims that the official product is a derivative work of their submission.

So to answer the question in the title of your question: No, Konami will not accept this. It doesn't matter if it's the most brilliantly designed card in the history of Yu-Gi-Oh, they're going to ignore it.

Comment: This is a big factor. A quick example is they could have developed a card for an future expansion and if a fan submits a similar card before it is released they could have to deal with claims that they got the idea from the fan.